# New-PSsession not working in Script

Tags: powershell

I have a strange problem with one of my servers :

I am trying to open a PSsession with it. 
If I copy my script directly in powershell everything works fine, but if i run it via a .ps1 file I get a access denied error.

The same sript works on multiple machines except this one.

Additonal information:

Executing Server : Server 2012

Target Server2003SP2

Another Server2003SP2 is working fine without a Problem

the Client Server was configured using :

```
 Enable-PSRemoting -Force
 Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts MY2012Server -concatenate -force
 Restart-Service WinRM
```

And the Error Message:

```
 New-PSSession : [Server2003SP2] Connecting to remote server Server2003SP2 failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information,
 Help topic.
 At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Script.ps1:23 char:13
 +  $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Servername -credential $Cred #-sessionO ...
 +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Edit : My full SCript as requested :

```
$Password = "Hereismypasswordwith@and€init"
$Username = "Servername\Administrator"
$Servername = "Servername" 
$Language = {

$oscode = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction continue 
$oscode = $oscode.oslanguage 
$switch = switch ($oscode){
           1031 {"Deutsch"};
                              1033 {"English"};
           default {"English"};             
                           }            
write-host $switch
return $switch

}

 $SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
 $Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassWord
 $pssessionoption = new-pssessionoption -operationtimeout 7200000 -IdleTimeout 7200000
 $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Servername -credential $Cred -sessionOption $pssessionoption
 Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock $Language 
 Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
```

UPDATE :

it seems to be something within the Char encoding.

the password in the ps1 file produces a difrent output for the € in it : 
in the ps1. ¬ 
in the ps window : ?

if i pass the Password as a Paramter it also works.

$password.gethash() also prouces difrent outputs. codepage is the same though (chcp)

the script was created in notepad++

Comment: Where's $Cred coming from?

Comment: `$SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force`
 `$Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassWord` I wont tell you more though ;-) as said this works completly fine outside of a ps1 file. on the server in question + if i just manualy copy the hole script in a powershell window it works fine even for the server in question. as a sidenote perhaps : the password contains a @ and a € symbol. maybe that screws with powershell?

Comment: yeah - good to be careful :) can you post most\any of the script?

Comment: PSRemoting doesn't need to be enabled on the client but it does need to be enabled on the server and you do have to run the client script from an elevated/admin console.  Have you done that? Also if you are adding trusted hosts, it should be the *server name* added on the client side.

Comment: Added the full Script as wished. it is basicly a small testscript since im running into some problems with localized Server versions. if i just copy paste everything in a powershell window it works. if i replace the Servername with another Server it works. trustedhosts are added on the executing server and the client server.

Comment: Do you know that you can add  `-computername` parameter of gwmi?

Comment: Did you create the script in Powershell ISE? Try taking the code which works when pasted into the command prompt, and paste it into a new file in ISE, then see if that file works.

Comment: -computername doesnt work (access denied on all machines) and since i have a session open anyway i thought i go this way. At least found the problem now, the € in the password. if i write-host the password in the Script it echos :  '¬ if i copy the script it echos me ?.

Comment: you can use notepad to check the encoding you are saving the script as. from a quick test my powershell console doesn't displaying ANSI caharacters over 127 (e.g. [char]126 displays a ~ but char[128] displays the ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing / Converting to ansi from UTC without BOM fixed the issue.. jesus crist who thinks about stuff like that / why the hell was it set to this value..